# Watch doesn't execute during testing for props

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

When I run the following unit-test for my Vue component, the watcher on my prop seemingly does not activate and does not modify the data I want to test. I am using vitest.

`Component.spec.ts`

```
it("should change array", asnyc () => {

  const obj = {}
  const wrapper = mount(component, {
    props: {
      someProp: object
    },
  });
  
  const new_object = {
    someData: 1234
  };
  await wrapper.setProps({
   someProp: new_object,
  });

  // I added $nextTick here in the hope it would do smth, but it didn't
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

  expect(wrapper.vm.someData).toEqual([
    { foo: 'bar' }
  ]);
```

`Component.vue`

```
<template></template>
<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      someData: ref([]);
    };
  },
  props: {
    someProp: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    someProp: {
      handler(new_obj) {
        someData.push({foo: 'bar'});
      }
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
  },
  setup(props) {
    props.someProb;
  },
});
</script>
```

When I run the test, it fails with the following message:

```
  - Array [
  -   Object {
  -     "foo": "bar",
  -   },
  - ]"
  + "Array []"
```

This is not how I would expect the test to behave. What am I doing wrong?